# function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr] sprintf

Tags: arrays, c, string, printf, return-type

i ma new c and i am trying sprintf along with pointers. all i get in console is return buf; as is please help me with this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* stringa(char* str);
int main()
{
    char* ss = "123";
    stringa(ss);

    return 0;
}

char* stringa( char* str)
{
    char buf [100] ;
    sprintf(buf,"hello %s", str);
    return buf;

}
```

i tried many other ways too like sprintf_c and my computer shut down for serious. i am learning c.

Comment: The lifetime of the variable `buf` ends when the function `stringa` returns. A simple solution would be a `static` variable, e.g. `static char buf [100] ;`. `static` variables will kepp their value between function calls. This has the drawback that the return value of `stringa` will point to a single buffer which gets overwritten in every call to `stringa`. You should also make sure that `sprintf` will not write past the end of `buf`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* stringa(char* dest, char* src)

int main()
{
    char buf [100] ;
    char* ss = "123";
    printf("%s\n", stringa(buf, ss));

    return 0;
}

char* stringa(char* dest, char* src)
{
    sprintf(dest,"hello %s", src);
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to also pass `sizeof(buf)` as an argument to `stringa` to allow prevention of buffer overflow.

Comment: thank you it works i wana know i was facing all the problem because my buff was getting destroyed after function end, and if i had buff as global variable would it had work just curious

Comment: @Zaheer yes, a global would have worked but... avoid globals

Answer (score 0):

In function 'char* stringa(char* str)' you are not allocating space in the heep for the char array 'buf' you are allocating space on the stack for that variable. (meaning after the function finishes, the variable 'buf' will be wiped away because it will be out of scope) therefore you must ask the compiler to allocate space in memory for this array, I recommend using malloc()

ex:

```
char* stringa( char* str)
{
char *buf  = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
sprintf(buf,"hello %s", str);
return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char* stringa( char* str)
> {
>     char buf [100] ;
>     sprintf(buf,"hello %s", str);
>     return buf;
>
> }
> ```

The problem with this code is that the `buf` `char` array is *local* to the `stringa` function. When the function returns, the memory occupied by the `buf` array is *not* valid anymore (for example, it could be reused later to store the content of other variables, arrays, etc.).

So when the function returns, you are giving the caller a pointer to *garbage memory*, to invalid data. The C compiler is trying to help you with that warning message; it's telling you: *"Sorry, you are trying to pass back to the caller the address of a local variable (i.e. the buf char array) that is not valid anymore when the function terminates."*

To fix this problem one option could be to allocate the `char` array for the output string at the **call site**, and let the invoked `stringa` function write into the caller-provided array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* stringa(char* dest, const char* str);

int main()
{
    const char* ss = "123";
    char buf[100];
    stringa(buf, ss);

    return 0;
}

/* Write the final message into 'dest'.
 * Return the same dest address.
 */
char* stringa(char* dest, const char* str)
{
    /* Note: better using a safe string function 
     * to prevent buffer overflows (e.g. sprintf_s),
     * passing the maximum destination array size as well.
     */
    sprintf(dest,"hello %s", str);
    return dest;    
}
```

Note that I also added some `const`s in your code to enforce some const-correctness for read-only input strings.